# Cannot access a disposed object after HttpClient.SendAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, mediatr

We have a dotnet-core 2.1 web-api project setup as following.
We are trying to use MediatR together with a HttpClient and send events for different responses in the HttpMagicService. Problem arrises when trying to use an injected service after a call to `HttpClient.SendAsync()`.

**Initial setup for `IMagicService` and MediatR.**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // other services configured above
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestLoggingBehavior<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPerformanceBehaviour<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(ApplicaitonCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly); 
    services.AddHttpClient<IMagicService, HttpMagicService>();
}
```

**Implementation of `IMagicService`.**

```
public class HttpMagicService : IMagicService
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public HttpMagicService(IMediator mediator, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
        this.httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(Magic data, Metadata metadata)
    {
        // This one works
        await this.mediator.Publish(new MagicAddInitIntegrationEvent(data));

        var url = metadata.RemoteUri + "/command/AddMagic";
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        {
            try
            {
                var httpContent = CreateHttpContent(data);
                request.Content = httpContent;
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", metadata.AuthKey);

                // httpClient clears the ResolvedServices?!
                var response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // This one fails
                    await this.mediator.Publish(new MagicAddIntegrationEvent(data));
                }
                else
                {
                    await this.mediator.Publish(new MagicAddFailedIntegrationEvent(data));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await this.mediator.Publish(new MagicAddFailedIntegrationEvent(meeting, ex));
            }
        }
    }

    private static HttpContent CreateHttpContent(object content)
    {
        // ...
    }       
}
```

For our first call `await this.mediator.Publish(new MagicAddInitIntegrationEvent(data));` the event is published and the handler can handle the event.

Looking at `this.mediator` we see that there is a resolved service for it.

[image: Resolved services before]

When we run the `var response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);` it seems like the httpClient just decides to dispose all services for everyone.

When looking at `this.mediator` after this line we see that everything is cleaned.

[image: Resolved services after]

Since there are no services the call `await this.mediator.Publish(new MagicAddIntegrationEvent(data));` wont be able to run and we get an exception.

[image: Exception thrown]

Is that the intended behavior for `this.httpClient.SendAsync`? Should we do it in another way?

One solution that seems to work is to ignoring setting the `services.AddHttpClient<IMagicService, HttpMagicService>();` and instead set a singleton service for `HttpClient`, this seems to work, but i´m not sure if that´s the right approach.

---

**Solution**

Used Panagiotis Kanavos suggestion and did a scoped httpClient, so my solution changed to this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // other services configured above
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestLoggingBehavior<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPerformanceBehaviour<,>));
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(ApplicaitonCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly); 
    services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
}
```

If trying to use the IMediator inside the scope without using `var mediator= scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();`, same problem as before did arise. So there was some scope problem with the DI container that i've missed.

```
public class HttpMagicService : IMagicService
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;
    private readonly IServiceProvider services;

    public HttpMagicService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        this.services = services?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(Magic data, Metadata metadata)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var httpClient = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
            var mediator= scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
         ...
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202914/discussion-on-question-by-johan-obrink-cannot-access-a-disposed-object-after-htt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions like this often occur when a singleton service tries to consume a scoped service. [This question about MediatR and scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008673/mediatr-scope-problems) may be relevant. In any case, HttpClientFactory recycles HttpClient instances (specifically *handler* instances) periodically, which means that if `HttpMagicService` caches the HttpClient instance long enough, it will get disposed at some point.

In either case, you may be able to use HttpClient by injecting IServiceProvider  into HttpMagicService and creating a scope explicitly. Check [consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task-1).

You can inject IServiceProvider instead of HttpClient, and create a scope inside the `AddAsync` method, eg :

```
public class HttpMagicService : IMagicService
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;
    private readonly IServiceProvider services;

    public HttpMagicService(IMediator mediator, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
        this.services = services?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(Magic data, Metadata metadata)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var httpClient = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
         ...
        }
```

Comment: If the scope of the instance is short lived.... You will eventually exhaust the socket in the machine and your HttpClient will crash with SocketException.  Remember that HttpClient is meant to be used as a SINGLE instance during the entire lifetime of the application.

Comment: The document YOU posted reads: "Therefore, HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. That issue will result in SocketException errors."